# No wifi drivers being installed on Acer Nitro 7

Tags: 18.04, drivers, wireless, acer, secure-boot

I have a brand new Acer Nitro-AN715-51, which shipped with Windows 10 and - unfortunately - Microsoft Secure Boot.

Installing 18.04 LTS itself off of a USB stick wasn't a problem, but now the computer is telling me that it can't find an adapter for wifi (or Bluetooth, for that matter). Booting into the Windows partition allowed use of the wifi with no trouble, so it's not a hardware issue.

I suspect it *may* have something to do with 'MOK', which I didn't really know what to do with when I was unexpectedly dropped into it while restarting to finalize the installation (I now have no way of getting back to the blue MOK screen). I have disabled Secure Boot now, but I'm unsure whether it was still on when first installing Ubuntu - could this have had something to do with not managing to install third-party drivers for the wifi?

EDIT:

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` (copied by hand, because I obviously can't access the internet on the device in question)

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0084]
```

and of `rfkill list`:

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
```

I forgot to mention this previously, but my trackpad also doesn't work (have again confirmed it's not a hardware issue via Windows). I assume this is also a driver issue? I also can't seem to get internet when I plug in an ethernet cable, which limits my options for installing things significantly. At this point, I'm actually amazed that the external mouse *does* work.

EDIT:

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. `uname -a` returns

```
Linux drubbels 4.15.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 17 15:39:52 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: What is the kernel version? With the HWE 5.3 kernel it should work. If you installed 18.04.4, it would work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this for myself in the following way:

```
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Navigate to the 'Additional Drivers' tab in the 'Software & Updates' application. Under the heading for the network card (listed as 'Intel Corporation: unknown' in my case), check the 'Using iwlwifi driver backport in DKMS format from backport-iwlwifi-dkms (open source)' option.

Everything then worked fine (after rebooting).

Comment: It was much better to install anoter kernel. This solution really works, but it's not perfect and may stop working.

Comment: I don't know the kernel version. `uname -a` returns `Linux drubbels 4.15.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 17 15:39:52 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: If you remove `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` and install `linux-genreic-hwe-18.04` you'll have the 5.3 kerenel. Why didn't you install 18.04.5 that has this kernel initially?  It shows 18.04.4, but you installed 18.04. I am tired of explaining this every time.

Comment: Why didn't I install 18.04.5 initially? Hell if I know, I made an Ubuntu USB a while ago and just followed some tutorial. I just used the version they recommended.

Comment: I'm very sorry that you're "tired of explaining this every time", but no one's forcing you to. I have *very* little experience with all this stuff and I'm just trying to make this work. If you're willing to offer free advice, then I'm really very grateful. If you're not, then that's totally fine too, but that's going to make contributing to stackexchange a challenge.